# PC のネットワーク通信をデバッグしたい

Tags: macos, network, http, https, debugging

開発しているwebアプリがAPIにアクセスしていてMacからリクエストが飛んでいるのですが、そのリクエストが飛んでいる状態と通信の中身を確認したいのですが、wiresharkのようなアプリを使って通信を確認する事ができるのでしょうか？
そして他にもおすすめのツール等があれば教えて頂けないでしょうか？

HTTPSによるリクエストかと思われます。
例えば自分が開発してないアプリ等の通信もデバックできるような状態であると汎用性があり嬉しいです。

宜しくお願い致します。

#### 追記

> 「webアプリ」とはWebブラウザー上で動作するアプリケーションを指していますでしょうか？

- そうです。webアプリはwebブラウザでローカルサーバにアクセスして操作するものを指しています。
  なので外部APIへのリクエスト自体はバックエンドから飛んでいます。

> 「自分が開発してないアプリ等」の記述もありますがこちらも同じくwebアプリなのか、それともWebブラウザーに限定しないアプリケーション全般なのか

- こちらはwebアプリに限らず、iTunes, Dropbox等のデスクトップアプリを想定して提示しました。

質問がふわっとしており申し訳ありません。

#### 使用目的

該当する開発中のwebアプリがAPIに通信を投げているのかどうかを知りたい。
コードベースで見れば良いのだが巨大でどこか分からないのとAPIにほんとに投げているのか知りたい。

#### 追記2

mitmproxyを使用してchromeが接続する際の通信内容は傍受出来たがターミナル等のデスクトップアプリでcURLを使用しリクエストを飛ばした際の内容は確認出来なかった。
セットアップに参考したサイト
[mitmproxyを使ってアプリの通信内容を確認する](https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2021/03/02/computer-windows-mac-network/)

Comment: 自身で名前を挙げた Wireshark ではだめな理由は何かありますか？単に "おすすめ" を聞く質問はクローズ対象と判断される可能性が高いです。もう少し具体的な要件を絞った方が回答もつきやすくなると思います。

Comment: 「webアプリ」とはWebブラウザー上で動作するアプリケーションを指していますでしょうか？ 「自分が開発してないアプリ等」の記述もありますがこちらも同じくwebアプリなのか、それともWebブラウザーに限定しないアプリケーション全般なのか、質問の範囲がわかりません。

Comment: 追記の内容を見ても、目的がいまいちはっきりしないです。「API に本当に投げているのか」は「API からのレスポンス」をチェックすればいいだけの様な気がします。

Comment: 情報が足りなくて申し訳ありません。テストコードでAPIへのアクセスがモックになっているんですけど、どこかでモック化出来ておらずAPIへのアクセスを疑っています。しかしそれ自体本当なのか分からないのでテストを実行してテストコードによってAPIへのアクセスが行われている知りたいのです。宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

WiresharkだとHTTPSのデコードが大変なので、Proxy型のキャプチャツールの方がよいでしょう。例えば著名なツールとして[Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload)があります。

ただし、

- APIへの通信がProxyに向くようにする
- HTTPSをデコードする関係で証明書をねつ造するのでそのままでは通信できなくなるので対策する

は必要です。いきなりAPIの通信でやるとハードルが高いのでクライアントでブラウザの通信を覗くところからやってみるとよいでしょう

使い方はいろんな人が解説記事を書いてくれてるので検索しみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。HTTPSでもどこのURLにリクエスト投げてる等はデコードしなくても分かるのでしょうか？

Comment: これってmacがネットに繋がる際に通る通信をプロキシに向けて全ての通信をBurp Suiteに向けたり出来るのでしょうか？確認したいのはそもそもAPIへの接続が行われているのか調べたいです。